# NGINX: configure multiple locations to different directories

Tags: nginx

I want to define a separate directory for each part of my website on my NGINX server.

```
domain.com/                     -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/website
domain.com/blog/                -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/blog
domain.com/checkout/            -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/checkout
domain.com/download/            -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/download
domain.com/forum/               -->     /var/www/html/domain.com/forum
```

The different configurations I've tried don't work, I get 404 errors.

```
server {
    location /  {
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    }
    
    location /blog  {
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/blog;
    }
}
```

or

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    
    location /blog  {
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/blog;
    }
}
```

or

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    
    location /blog/  {
        alias /var/www/html/domain.com/blog;
    }
}
```

or

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    
    location /blog/  {
        alias /var/www/html/domain.com/blog/;
    }
}
```

or

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/domain.com;
    
    location /  {
        alias /var/www/html/domain.com/website/;
    }
    
    location /blog/  {
        alias /var/www/html/domain.com/blog/;
    }
}
```

or

```
server {
    location ~ ^/(?!(blog|checkout|download|forum))/ { 
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    } 
    
    location /blog/  {
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/blog;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration solved my problem

```
server {
    location / { 
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    } 
    
    location ~ ^/(?!(blog|checkout|download|forum))/ { 
        root /var/www/html/domain.com/website;
    } 
    
    location /blog/  {
        alias /var/www/html/domain.com/blog/;
    }
}
```